# 500 Internal Server Error On my website pages

Tags: error-handling, internal-server-error

When I open my website and any website pages, I get a "500 Internal Server Error".  In the host, no .htaccess file exists.

The website works properly, but when I open any website pages, it's giving a 500 internal server error.

Please tell me what's the problem in the website.

Comment: Might it be *because* you're lacking a .htaccess file? Most moderns CMSes use them for URL rewriting -- my guess is the 500's from trying to access a rewritten URL. Regardless, try creating a .htaccess file with the following lines: 
`php_flag  display_errors        on
php_value error_reporting       2039` (Note that there should be a line-break after "on", but comments don't allow them.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can find more information on the kind of internal server error that happened in you webserver's error log file. (e.g. /var/log/httpd/error_log on many systems).

Answer (score 0):

You may be work with a new version php in local server. But your hosted server may have older version php. Just upgrade your php version in cpanel 
[upgrade php version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niaP5.jpg)

Comment: I think that you are making a lot of assumptions, and not explaining them. My first line of troubleshooting would be to recommend looking at the error.log